# ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.dll": unknown error 126?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, windows-10

I have got this message when I wanted to create a new extension. [image]

How can I solve this problem? I have Win10 64 bit and PostgreSQL 11.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Comment: I have a similar error also with Win10 64 bit and PostgreSQL 11.
ERROR: could not load library "C:/PostgreSQL/11/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.dll": The specified module could not be found. State SQL: XX000
rtpostgis-2.5.dll is in the folder of the path that error indicates.

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope someone answers

Comment: I have the same problem, let me provide some of the steps I've taken just in case it helps anyone resolve it: 

I've re-downloaded everything, restarted my computer, made sure I installed the latest proj4 and GDAL, installed through stackbuilder, installed through WSL apt-get.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same mistake and it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

Just copy these two .dlls ("`libeay32.dll`" and "`ssleay32.dll`") from `bin/postgisgui` folder and paste them in the `bin` folder.

Source: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4482

Comment: Voted up because did work for me as well.

Comment: I agree, this worked for me too on Windows 10 with PostgreSQL 9.6.

Comment: work for me too. Postgresql 9.6

Comment: This worked for me using PostgreSQL 10.17

Comment: Work for me too, PostgreSQL 10 on Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

So this worked for me but no promises because I don't really know what I did I just followed some stuff I found else where. Now I'm on win 10 installing PostgreSQL 11.5 and postgis 2.5 (installed through the native application stack builder) all 64bit and I just did a new install of them all.

Then I followed the instructions [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4482) and copped the dll files "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" from Postgresql>11>bin>postgisgui into the bin folder just above it. Note I did all of this without having opened up pgadmin or anything else yet, idk if that would have an effect on this. Then I opened up pgadmin 4 and went to the db I wanted to enable postgis on and instead of querying "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" (bc that didnt wana work and threw a new error) I used the gui tree on the left and went to extension>create extension and created an extension to postgis. At that point everything seemed to be working as normal, and I installed the rest of the extensions according to the normal querying style (exp "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology") and was able to execute all the commands to the right of this [page](https://postgis.net/install/) without error. This is the full response to "SELECT postgis_full_version();"

"POSTGIS="2.5.2 r17328" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.7.0-CAPI-1.11.0 3.7.1" SFCGAL="1.3.2" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" TOPOLOGY RASTER"

I did a little bit of messing around and it seems to not be throwing any errors when calling functions but I havnt tested it thoroughly.

Comment: Oh my goodness, no idea why this works, but it works.