# Error in adding PostGIS extension :- rtpostgis-2.4.dll could not be loaded

Tags: windows, postgresql-10, postgis-2.4

I need to created web based application to showcase GIS data using .Net technology.

After going through couple of blogs and links, I installed Postgress 10 and PostGIS  2.4. When i tried to add PostGIS extension to postgress SQL it gave me below error message:

```
"ERROR: could not load library "E:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.dll": The specified module could not be found."
```

Same error was with PostGIS version 2.5. I also tried to use "PostGIS Shapefile and DBF Uploader utility" , But it gives below message:

```
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Shapefile import failed.
```

Sample shape file for your reference : https://github.com/anthonydb/practical-sql/blob/master/Chapter_14/tl_2010_us_county10.zip

I tried with my shapefile and from the link above , But the error is same.

I have reinstalled everything again but it did not work!

Comment: As per : https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_FAQ.html#idm26452 , I dont have libgdal-1.dll in my bin folder

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by copying "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" from bin/postgisgui folder and paste them in bin folder. Refer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331653/error-could-not-load-library-c-program-files-postgresql-11-lib-rtpostgis-2-5