# Error when creating PostGIS extension in pgAdmin4

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to create a PostGIS extension in pgAdmin4.

When typing `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, or through "db_name > Create > Extension > General > Name = postgis", I get this error:

> ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program
>   Files/PostgreSQL/12/lib/postgis-2.5.dll": The specified procedure
>   could not be found.

What I have done so far:

1) I've checked [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/331653/error-could-not-load-library-c-program-files-postgresql-11-lib-rtpostgis-2-5) question that addressed the same issue, and moved the two .dlls ("libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll"), as suggested, but the error remains.

2) I have verified that "libxml2-2.dll" is in the bin folder.

3) I've restarted pgAdmin4 but didn't help as well.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Version: 
PostgreSQL 12.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit / PostGIS 2.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall PostGIS by the following executable on this page :  http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/windows/pg12/

The download will allow you to get the necessary dll files. 
When PgAdmin4 was released, when you installed PostGIS with StackBuilder, some files were missing. They updated the executable a few days later and the problem was solved.